# Using /get requestHandler in solrj search

Tags: solrcloud

I need to use the "/get" request handler using solrj code in solr 4.10. I am using CloudSolrServer to run my solr queries. Can someone tell me the exact way to use that request handler through solrj. Setting solrQuery.setRequestHandler("/get") and the query as 
setSolrQuery("id=1") or setSolrQuery("id:1") does not bring back any results.

Using curl command and running the query as 
curl -i 'http://localhost:8983/solr/collection/get?id=1' does bring back results though.

I believe there is some specific way we need to pass the solr document id while using the get request handler. Any leads would be appreciated.